# std::atomic trivially copyable structs

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, c++14, atomic

C++ reference says: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

> std::atomic may be instantiated with any TriviallyCopyable type T

However following example does not work under g++ 6.2.0

```
#include <atomic>
#include <functional>

struct Test11 {
    int x;
};
struct Test12 {
    char x;
};
struct Test13 {
    long x;
};
struct Test2 {
    char x;
    int y;
};
struct Test3 {
    int y;
    long x;
};

template<typename T, typename... ARGS>
void test(ARGS&& ... args) {
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value);

    std::atomic<T> a;
    a.store(T{std::forward<ARGS>(args)...});
}

int main() {
    test<Test11>(1);
    test<Test12>('\1');
    test<Test13>(1L);
    test<Test2>('\1',2);
    test<Test3>(1,2L);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile: `g++-6 -std=c++14 -latomic test.cpp`

> /tmp/cchademz.o: In function `std::atomic<Test3>::store(Test3, std::memory_order)`:
>   test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6atomicI5Test3E5storeES0_St12memory_order[_ZNSt6atomicI5Test3E5storeES0_St12memory_order]+0x3e): undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16`
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

`g++-6 --version`

> g++ (Ubuntu 6.2.0-7ubuntu11) 6.2.0 20161018

Especially I do not understand why `Test2` works but `Test3` does not.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** added -latomic flag and g++ version

Comment: Did you try adding `-latomic` at the end of the compilation line by chance? The code compiles fine on coliru with `-latomic` (g++6.2): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd421bd3d1715897

Comment: Could you try to include <cstdatomic> instead?

Comment: moving `-latomic` to the end worked. But why?

Comment: @WaeCo On Coliru, it works even if you put `-latomic` before `test.cpp`. This is probably linked to the linker used, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc.

Comment: Ok did not know that. But why does it compile if I comment out Test3 without linking libatomic?

Comment: @WaeCo `Test3` is the only struct with a size greater than `8` (on standard architectures), so the compiler probably does not need a specific function for storing atomically structure with a size smaller than 8 bytes (`std::atomic<>::store` is probably specialized for small types).

Comment: @WaeCo Typically, if you check the generated ASM (e.g. on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/8cLZXC)), you'll see that up to 8 bytes, the compiler uses the `mov QWORD ...` instruction, but there are no instructions to move more than 8 bytes at once, which is why you need a custom function.

Comment: Thanks. Would you add this as answer so I can mark it as resolved

Comment: @KevinG there is no such header as `<cstdatomic>`, so that's not going to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @TartanLlama in its now-deleted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40739406/2666289), you need to link against `libatomic`:

```
g++-6 -std=c++14 test.cpp -latomic
```

You need to add `-latomic` at the end of the compilation line. Some compilers (linkers) may work correctly if you put `-latomic` before `test.cpp` (e.g. `g++` on Coliru), but some won't (see [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)).

**Disclaimer:** I am not an expert in linkage, so I cannot provide a detailed explanation as to why it works with `-latomic` before on some platform and not on other (I am guessing the linkers are different, but... ).

---

As to why your code compiles if you remove `Test3`, this is compiler and architecture dependent. If you look at the generated ASM with `-O2` and `g++6.2` on *godbolt*:

```
sub     rsp, 24
movabs  rax, 8589934593
mov     ecx, 5
mov     DWORD PTR [rsp], 1
mov     rdi, rsp
mov     esi, 1
mov     edx, 2
mfence
mov     BYTE PTR [rsp], 1
mfence
mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], 1
mfence
mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rax
mfence
call    __atomic_store_16
```

You see that for structure that takes less than 8 bytes (`Test1X`, `Test2`), the compiler can use the `mov QWORD` instruction (a qword is usually 8 bytes long on nowadays architectures), but it cannot generate a single instruction to handle the cases where the size is strictly greater than 8 (`sizeof(Test3)` will usually be 16).

Basically, there is probably a specialization of `std::atomic<T>` (or of some operations of `std::atomic<T>`) in `g++`<sup>1</sup> when `T` is "small", and the definition of "small" is probably architecture dependent.

**Disclaimer:** Again, I am not an expert regarding `<atomic>` so this is mainly from experiments regarding generated ASM on godbolt and behaviour of `g++` and `clang` on Coliru.

<sub><sup>1</sup> `clang` has a `__atomic_store_8` procedure and a `__atomic_store` procedure, and without `-latomic` it will not compile for `Test2` and `Test3`. However it manages to compile `Test13` even if `sizeof(Test13)` is 8 so it does not use `__atomic_store_8` for some structures. `icc` has a completely different behavior and does not generate any `call` (cannot test on Coliru, but you can look it up on godbolt).</sub>